# How can I use ffmpeg to stream my USB connected Android device

Tags: networking, usb, ffmpeg, vpn, android

I want to use my android device as an external monitor.

There are methods using VPN, but they are slow. If you connect two Tablet it becomes unusable, because the bigger the full display amount is, it will get rendered fully on the VPN client.

So with ffmpeg I can grab a portion of the screen and cast only that are

Until now I have these

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0+7680,1080 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -r 60 -f mpegts -listen 1 rtmp://localhost:1935/
```

it returns:

```
    built with gcc 10 (SUSE Linux)  configuration: --prefix=/usr --     libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 
 cut cmmand details
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[x11grab @ 0x55ed2db79b40] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0+7680,1080':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1618395766.466413, bitrate: 3981312 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1920x1080, 3981312 kb/s, 60 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 111 (Connection refused)
rtmp://localhost:1935/test/: Unknown error occurred
```

With the ADB command:

```
adb reverse tcp:1935 tcp:1935
```

but only TCP not UDP.

with the ADB command:

```
adb forward tcp:1935 tcp:1935
```

I can forward the host port request to the  android device

It is possible to redirect the port 1935 to the host computer.

If I connect connect to localhost:1935 on the android tablet, it is direclty redirected to the host. But apparantly I am wrong here.

Do I need ffserver or similar?

with the command

```
adb shell monkey -p [xxx.appname.xxx] -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

is it possible to open an app from the desktop.
that is where I am at, I don't know from here.

What i want to replace is a method like this using VNC

[Android as external display for linux with VNC](https://youtu.be/u17xNiSvr24)

I expect faster output with ffmpeg and rtmp

With Android to LInux it is easy and straight forward, should't it be possible the other way round?

```
adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -
```

Comment: Can you connect to this stream and view it on your PC? Have you tried viewing the stream in VLC on android? Just "connecting" to it doesn't tell us what you have actually done.

Comment: `monkey` is a tool for testing apps. It sends random touches to the app. I don't think that this is what you want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than posting comments. You can put a lot more useful information and properly format it when it is in your question.

Comment: I already edited the question, and posted the output